# Machtzis Hashekel WHEN

Tags: purim, money

When are we supposed to give machtzis Hashekel exactly and Why is the custom to give machtzis hashekel before Purim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is given on Taanis Esther before Mincha. The reason we give it, is to recall the half-shekel that was donated annually to the Temple treasury in the month of Adar.

http://www.aish.com/h/pur/m/48965736.html

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/260799/jewish/The-Laws-of-Giving-a-Half-of-Shekel.htm

Answer (score 3):

*Rama* says to give it before the *mincha* before *Purim* (he quotes that from the *Minhagim* and says that that's the accepted practice). *Mishna B'rura* then cites *Magen Avraham* as having said that the custom where and when he was was to give it at *shacharis*, before reading the *m'gila*, on *Purim*. *Mishna B'rura* then concludes (citing *P'ri M'gadim*) that the common practice *now* (or when he wrote, a century or so ago) is to give it before *mincha* [before *Purim*]. (This is all in 694:1.) As always, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) for a practical ruling.